# Calling a twig extension that returns an array once, using contents multiple times

Tags: twig

I have a Twig extension which returns an array, here is the code:

```
public function getUserSettings($user_id){
    $user_preferences = array(
        'background_color' => '#000000',
        'text_color' => '#FFFFFF'
    );
}
```

If I dump this array ( {{ dump(getUserSettings(app.user.id)) }} ) and I have which is fine:

```
array:2 [▼
  "background_color" => "#000000"
  "text_color" => "#FFFFFF"
]
```

In the Twig template I don't want to have a call to this function each time I want the background_color or the text_color.

Is there a way to assign the returning array to a twig array and then use it in the template?

Comment: `{% set arr = get_user_setting(id) %}`

Comment: Incredibly simple. That worked. Thanks DarkBee.